# Sustituir espacios de cadena de entrada

Tags: java, string

Tengo un método que recibe un String , pero quiero que se sustituya cada espacio en la cadena de entrada por una cadena formada por tres espacios. ¿Cómo podría empezar eso? ¿Con un replace?

Comment: Te recomiendo editar el titulo, para que si otros ven esto en Google o en el listado puedan tener mejor idea de que es lo que buscas.

Comment: Gracias por por decirlo , dicho y hecho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_replace.htm

Deberia de ser algo del estilo:

```
String s= x.replace(' ','   ');
```

Comment: Exacto , así es , funciona. Yo pensaba algo similar , pero al final resulta que es muy sencillo. Gracias por tu respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Sí, es con la función replace en java.

```
string funcionReemplazarEspacios(string cadena) {
    return cadena.replace(" ", "   ");
}
```